# ajax to Proceed depending upon the response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using folowing code to save imag file on machine , image is saved if user is authentic otherwise signup page should be shown . but after saving image page is refreshing or on authentication failure not redirecting to sign up. what is the problem?

**js ajax**::

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "userLoginAction.php",
  data: {image: dataURL,uname:uname,pwd:pwd}
}).done(function( respond ) {
 alert("Downloading Completed"+respond);
 console.log('back on download js**');
});
```

**PHP  userLoginAction.php ::**

```
<?php 
include("sessionHandler.php");
include("../connect.php");
$con = connectDb();
$db = SelectDB($con);

$username = $_REQUEST['uname'];
$password = $_REQUEST['pwd'];
$img= $_POST['image'];

// To protect MySQL injection
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email ='".$username."' AND user_password='".$password."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1){
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file 
    createLoginSession($username,$password);
    include 'download.php'; 

}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password".$img;
    header("location:signup.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because redirection doing in server side will not work with ajax.You have to do the redirection in the success of your ajax like this..Try something like this

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "userLoginAction.php",
  data: {image: dataURL,uname:uname,pwd:pwd}
}).done(function( respond ) {
   if(respond == 'download'){
      alert("Downloading Completed"+respond);
      console.log('back on download js**');
   }
   else if(respond == 'login'){
      window.location = "url/to/loginpage";
   }
});
```

PHP

```
include("sessionHandler.php");
include("../connect.php");
$con = connectDb();
$db = SelectDB($con);


$username = $_REQUEST['uname'];
$password = $_REQUEST['pwd'];
$img= $_POST['image'];


// To protect MySQL injection
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email ='".$username."' AND user_password='".$password."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1){
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
    createLoginSession($username,$password);
    include 'download.php';
    echo 'download';

}
else {
    echo "login";
}
```

Comment: Alternatively he could retrieve the response header `location` and check it's value to redirect on client side.

Comment: actually i am simply printing alert("Downloading Completed"+respond);  in ajax done , but alert doesn't come ... instead page is refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "userLoginAction.php",
    data: {
        image: dataURL,
        uname:uname,
        pwd:pwd
    },
    success:function(data) {
        if (data == '**DOWNLOAD**') {
            alert('Download Completed');
        } else if (data == '**LOGIN**') {
            window.location.href = 'signup.php';
        }
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
include("sessionHandler.php");
include("../connect.php");
$con = connectDb();
$db = SelectDB($con);


$username = $_REQUEST['uname'];
$password = $_REQUEST['pwd'];
$img= $_POST['image'];


// To protect MySQL injection
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email ='".$username."' AND user_password='".$password."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1){
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
    createLoginSession($username,$password);
    include 'download.php';
    echo '**DOWNLOAD**';

}
else {
    echo "**LOGIN**";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To prevent the page from refreshing after the Ajax call, return false in your done function.

Comment: Doesn't matter in this case. His HTML does not even provide a link (which honestly is bad markup and destroys the purpose of the anchor element), so there will be no 'default action' which needs to be prevented.